# Analyzing this bode plot for frequency break point

Tags: capacitor, resistors, bode-plot

So given this problem:

[circuit http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/640x480q90/902/1FzzwZ.png](http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/640x480q90/902/1FzzwZ.png)

The correct bode plot for it is:

[bode plot http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/640x480q90/661/yILL19.png](http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/640x480q90/661/yILL19.png)

What I don't understand is how the -3db was measured. I know that -3db can be found through 20log(1/sqrt(2)), but how is it measured right at frequency 10kHz?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be careful, the x-axis is not frequency but radian frequency. So the break-point frequency is not 10 kHz but 10 krad/s.

Now you have the transfer function \$T(\omega)=\dfrac{1}{1+j\omega{}RC}\$ in your top picture. What is the absolute value of that function when \$\omega=1/RC\$?

What is \$1/RC\$ when R is 100 ohms and C is 1 uF?

Comment: Thanks. But why is the absolute value of w = 1/RC the breakpoint at 3dB?

Comment: @Willtd So you know that the magnitude of the gain is defined as: `|T(w)|`, and in decibels it is: `20 * log(|T(w)|)`, so now compute what `20 * log(|T(w)|)` is when `w = 1/RC`, like The Photon said

Comment: @Willtd, plug in 1/RC for w in the formula for T(w), then take the magnitude. What do you get?

Comment: 1/sqrt(2) => -3dB... wow, my heart skipped a beat.

Comment: @Willt:The best method for MEASURING this frequency is not the magnitude but the corresponding PHASE which is -45deg at this break point.